# How to call Popen with a different shell?

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a tool that takes a series of commands and executes them.

The commands are to be written like if they were typed in a terminal/console. To do that, I used `Popen()` with `shell=True` so to mimick the behavior of someone typing in a terminal/console.

Now I'd like to allow the user to specify the command interpreter he likes. More precisly, on Windows, one can decide to use its "Git bash" instead of cmd.exe.

According to [`Popen()`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), the choice of the interpreter to use is done through the environment variable `COMSPEC`.

I tried to set `COMSPEC` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe` before the call, but it fails, because subprocess adds `/c` to the command, while `base` expects `-c`.

I thought of not using `shell=True` but then I don't know exactly what the differences are:

- Should I `.split()` the command line into arguments ? If so, how ?
- Are there any flags that `shell=True` implies/set ?

The goal here is to not reimplement the "magic" inside `Popen(shell=True)` while still mimicking it the best I can.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 7):

`shell=True` is almost universally the wrong thing, and that isn't different here. In this case, where `your_command` is a string built for parsing by bash, use:

```
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe', "-c", your_command])
```

...and that command will be parsed only by the specified shell (the one provided by Git), rather than needing to be parsed by the shell at `COMSPEC` to generate a command for use by bash.

Comment: use `r""` literal or escape slashes (`"\b" != r"\b" == "\\b"`).